# Strange errors when Archiving iPhone app

Tags: ios, archive, armv6

So I am trying to archive my iPhone app for ad-hoc testing and I am getting some weird circumstances.  When I archive it, at the top where it says archive type, for some reason it says "Mac app archive" instead of the usual "iOS App Archive"

I do not know why this is happening, because this is not a mac App.

I have the following three warnings when I archive the app that may help, but I'm not sure.

The first is this one

```
iPhone/iPod Touch: application executable is missing a required architecture.  
At least     one of the following architecture(s) must be present: armv6 (-19033)
```

I am not sure why this is happening, because I have both armv6 and armv7 listed in valid architectures

The second warning I get is this

```
The CodeResources file is missing and it must be a symbolic link to
_CodeSignature/CodeResources.  Make certain that the bundle is on a locally-mounted volume
(not a remote SMB volume), and be certain to use the Mac OS X Finder to compress it  
(-19062)
```

Again, not sure why this is happening, or even what it means.

The last error is this one

```
Warning: The Copy Bundle Resources build phase contains this target's Info.plist file 'Catch It/Resources/Info.plist'.
```

I am really lost on that one, I don't know what it is trying to tell me.

Please help me, because I cannot distribute this ipa because it thinks it is a mac app.

Thanks

Comment: Which Xcode version are you using? Xcode 4.5 has no ARMV6 support anymore! For the older versions, make sure that ARMV6 is listed in both; `Valid Architectures` and `Architectures`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you are using Xcode 4.5.

I've just run into the same problem, and managed to solve the problem. My app is waiting for review now.

This is what I changed: In the target, I selected "Build phases", then in "Copy bundle resources" I removed the plist file.

If this doesn't fix your problem, also make sure you set the iOS deployment target to iOS 4.3 at least.

Edit: I also removed armv6 from both `Architectures`and `Valid Archictectures` in the build settings.

Answer (score 0):

I get message on Xcode 4.6.3

```
The CodeResources file is missing and it must be a symbolic link to
_CodeSignature/CodeResources.  Make certain that the bundle is on a locally-mounted volume
(not a remote SMB volume), and be certain to use the Mac OS X Finder to compress it  
(-19062)
```

when try Build app, after running it on Simulator. Change target to iOSDevise solve this problem.